# Email Service works just fine locally but it doesn't work when the site is deployed to godaddy host

Tags: vb.net, email

I have a function that sends email in my website.  My website is written in Visual Basic and my email sender function is below:

```
Dim mail As New MailMessage()
mail.Subject = Trim(TextBox1.Text())
mail.Body = Trim(TextBox2.Text())
Try
        Dim SmtpServer As New SmtpClient()
        SmtpServer.Host = "smtpout.secureserver.net"
        SmtpServer.Port = 80
        SmtpServer.Credentials = New Net.NetworkCredential("test@test.org", "password")
        mail.From = New MailAddress("admin@test.org")
        mail.To.Add("customer@test.org")
        mail.CC.Add(Trim(HiddenField1.Value()))
        mail.Subject = Trim(TextBox1.Text())
        mail.Body = Trim(TextBox2.Text())
        mail.IsBodyHtml = True
        SmtpServer.Send(mail)
        Response.Redirect("Welcome.aspx", False)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
    End Try
```

The email function and everything worked just fine on my local dev machine. But they never worked when I deployed to the windows hosting in GoDaddy. 
Here is what I get as an exception:

[image]

I know that GoDaddy has some strict rules for sending emails. But to avoid this, I couldn't find good documentation. What am I missing?

Comment: Does your mail server expect a connection from the godaddy host?  They may be blocking you at their firewall.

Comment: I think that their firewall is blocking my email service. Their customer service is not helping enough to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The host name is probably not the right one.

```
SmtpServer.Host = "smtpout.secureserver.net"
```

Godaddy mentions this as a blanket host for most of the SMTP related requests. But, they have actually implemented a system where each user is given a **sandboxed access to its SMTP service**.  The combination of hostname and port is used to uniquely identify the user.

You could find this in your settings, their terminology is email relay server.

Reference: 
[Godaddy](https://in.godaddy.com/help/find-your-email-relay-server-122)

Comment: You're right! The hosting server should be `relay-hosting.secureserver.net`

Comment: @GoGo Thank you for acknowledging :)